# AutoCompleteTextView AddTextChangedListener method in Android(Xamarin)

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, autocompletetextview

I want to Implement `AddTextChangedListener` to `AutoCompleteTextView` using `Android.Text.ITextWatcher` But I can't find any way on how to implement in Xamarin.

I am using `BigData` so every Single Character add in `AutoCompleteTextView` i want to call server to check the data. So I want to add `onTextChanged`, `beforeTextChanged` and `afterTextChanged` for my `AutoCompleteTextView`.

In pure Android I am using below way

```
txtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                                @Override
                                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                                    String newText = txtSearch.getText().toString();
                                    new getJsonData().execute(newText);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                                }
                            });
```

Any Help be Highly Appreciated.

**Update :**

[image]

See the Upper ScreenShot If user write something on `Medical Store` `AutoCompleteTextView` and select the value from Suggestion which is change every time when user write single new character. Then I want to set it `Address` if user select some value from data.

Comment: you dont need it: all you need is a `android.widget.Filterable` adapter instead

Comment: @pskink can you show How can I Implement It with every Single new charcter add by User I want to call the server data. Because `onTextChanged` require to call server new data.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830

Comment: @pskink but I want to set Other value base on Filter data in `onTextChanged` method.

Comment: what `"other value"`?

Comment: like if  User select `Name` then i want to directly set it `Address` to below `TextView`.

Comment: sorry if have no idea what TextView you are talking about

Comment: @pskink I update my question.

Comment: so you need `OnItemClickListener`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128449/discussion-between-ironman-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink first of all I want implement `onTextChanged` because on text change i want to pass that `string` to server which has query filter and give Filter data automatically so on new text write in `AutoComplete` I want to call server data that's why I Require `onTextChanged` this method. I Think now you have clear Idea What I want.

Comment: did you try the code i posted?

Comment: @pskink that is not work in my case because I describe full problem in the above comment.

Comment: it will work, just use my adapter and `OnItemClickListener`

Comment: @pskink your code is in `Java` can you post It How can i Implement because it totally confuse me.

Comment: no, i will not translate it to c#, you have to do that

Comment: @pskink I try it then come to you later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution.

In my Activity I have Extends with `Android.Text.ITextWatcher` and Implement Interface Method it will Create like below way

```
public void AfterTextChanged(IEditable s)
        {

        }

public void BeforeTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {

        }

public async void OnTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            string newText = autoCompleteTextView.Text;
            var suggestionData = await PrescriptionServices.GetFilterData(newText);

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.row_org, suggestionData);
            autoCompleteTextView.Adapter = adapter;

        }
```

Comment: seems you didnt get what i meant, take a look [here](http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java#856), as you can see `ACTV` already has `TextWatcher`  (called `MyWatcher`), just analize this source code and you will know how to use `ACTV` correctly